# $_POST not being set with AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

This should be a fairly simple call but I just can't seem to make it work. Basically, I'm trying to pass a set of search parameters to a PHP script but $_POST is coming up empty. The call (via jQuery)...

```
self.search = function () {
    var data = {
        'year': 2013,
        'month': 10,
        'day': 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'repositories/blogposts.php',
        data: { 'search': data },
        success: function(results) {
            // populate knockout vm with results...
        }
    });
};
```

The PHP code waiting to do something with the incoming json object...

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    echo find_blogposts(json_decode($_POST['search']));
}
```

I've tried this many ways but no matter what, `print_r($_POST)` gives me an empty array. What's missing?

Comment: Try with `data: { search: JSON.stringify(data) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is probably choking on the object you are trying to send.

You should either send the data object directly:

```
data: data,
```

(to get `$_POST['year']`, etc. in php)

or convert the object to a json string you can decode on the php side:

```
data: { 'search': JSON.stringify(data) },
```

Comment: I've tried both approaches, neither are working. Technically, the `dataType: 'json'` should force the object to become a JSON string.

Comment: @user1446184 No, `dataType: 'json'` specifies (and parses...) the result as json, it has nothing to do with the data sent to the server.

Comment: @user1446184 Also note that as you have specified the result to be parsed as json, you cannot just `echo` or `print_r` anything. Does `find_blogposts()` return valid json? Check the `net` tab of the developers tools to see what you really get back.

Comment: Well, I somehow managed to make it work. I did use the `JSON.stringify()' call and got the results to display, even though the result was coming back as a valid JSON regardless without it, even though there were PHP parsing errors. Will have to figure out what I did in the calls to cause this but so far it seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What does happen inside of `find_blogposts()`?

Alternatively you could try `.post()`.

```
$.post( "repositories/blogposts.php", { year: "2013", month:"10", day:"1" }, function( data ){
  // do something here
});
```

In your php just receive `$_POST['year']` which will be 2013.

Hope it helps.

Here is [api doc for .post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: We're not even getting as far as `find_blogposts()` because `$_POST` is empty. And no, `$.post()` also seems impotent here.